# How to Convert CPU code to GPU in an optimized manner?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, gpu, gpuimage

I am trying to work in GPU codes (still as a beginner) , but as this is my second task in it, compare to my previous task this is a bit different. I want to do two things in below code. 
1) to convert below code to GPU code 
2) but more specifically i want to make it as optimized code to run faster. 
The function is given below:

```
RF =  [4,3]; 
overlap= 1;
inhibatory = 0;
gap = RF-overlap;
ULS = size(err_sen{lay_no}); % suppose 6x6
Curr_LS = size(s.images{lay_no-1}); % Lower or current for which we are caculating weights in this case 19x19
p_Grad = grad.wGrad{lay_no}; % existing 19x19 values which will be updated
cur_sen = err_sen{lay_no}(:,:,:);  % upper layer values
tempGrad = zeros(Curr_LS(1), Curr_LS(2), Curr_LS(3)); % creating a tempGrad matrix for saving the data
curr_Input = s.images{lay_no-1}(:,:,:,samples_ind); % input source which will be multiplied with the other sensitivities of upper layer (cur_sen) 
cur_maps = net.map_struct{lay_no-1}; % this specifies which input image was used for calculating high layer image. 

for Cur_lay_Map = 1: Curr_LS(3)  % in each sample we have 13, 11, 9 maps (which reduces as layer goes up) 
    map_to_read = find(cur_maps(Cur_lay_Map,:));  % its a mat in which it specifies which it used suppose in this case of 13x11 where in each column we have 3 consecutive 1's (1, 2,3) and rest 0's, and than in next column another (2,3,4) 1's and rest zeros
    tempgrads = zeros(Curr_LS(1), Curr_LS(2));

    for ii=1: Curr_LS(1)  % for lower layer image pixels reading e.g in this case 19x19
        for jj=1: Curr_LS(2)
            uLowMax=ceil((ii-(RF+inhibatory))/(gap-inhibatory)); % calculating which pixels to read in upper layer of 6x6
            uHighMax=floor((ii-1)/(gap-inhibatory))+1;
            vLowMax=ceil((jj-(RF+inhibatory))/(gap-inhibatory));
            vHighMax = floor((jj-1)/(gap-inhibatory))+1;

            uLow=ceil((ii-RF)/gap); 
            uHigh= floor((ii-1)/gap)+1;
            vLow=ceil((jj-RF)/gap); 
            vHigh= floor((jj-1)/gap)+1;
            summed_value=0;
            uLowMax = max(uLowMax,1);
            uHighMax = min(uHighMax, ULS(1));
            vLowMax = max(vLowMax,1);
            vHighMax = min(vHighMax, ULS(2));
            for Up_map_sens = map_to_read % this states which three maps to read from 11 in each case
                UL_Sen = cur_sen(:,:,Up_map_sens);
                if(inhibatory==0) % this if it is in receptive field 
                    summed_value = summed_value + sum(sum(UL_Sen(uLowMax:uHighMax,vLowMax:vHighMax)));
                else % it is in inhibitory field but as we have 0 so not used currently
                    for u = uLowMax : uHighMax
                        for v = vLowMax : vHighMax
                            if(u>=uLow && u<= uHigh && v>=vLow &&v<=vHigh)
                                 summed_value = summed_value + UL_Sen(u,v);
                            else
                                 summed_value = summed_value - UL_Sen(u,v);
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
            cur_lay_nValue = curr_Input(ii,jj,Cur_lay_Map);
            summed_value = summed_value * cur_lay_nValue;
            tempgrads(ii,jj) = summed_value;
        end
     end
     tempG_all(:,:,Cur_lay_Map) = tempgrads(:,:);
  end
  newGrad(:,:) = prevGrad + sum(tempG_all,3);
  grad.wGrad{lay_no}(:,:) =  newGrad(:,:);
  clear newGrad;
end
```

I will be thankful for guidance and help in this regards. I am trying by myself for converting and optimizing but till now i am unsuccessful. Regards

Comment: That's a huge piece of code! Come on, make it easier for us. It's unlikely that someone will read all that to answer

Comment: That's a lot of code. Could you minimize it to just the part(s) that you think could be optimized?

Comment: Ok wait few minutes.. Sorry for that..

Comment: Is it ok or should i make it more shorter. As it is said, that some time even that variable, struct management also take time. If properly not created like (in advance) , or creating struct of images the way i used s.images{lay_no-1}(:,:,:,samples_ind); rather than s{lay_no-1}.images(:,:,:,samples_ind); which i used before. (it gave me some time saving).. and many more

Comment: How about briefly explaining what it does in English too?

Comment: i added some further comments… Hope it will be helpful

Comment: I can minimize it further but than will be hard to understand. However basic idea of this question is to:                     1) minimize loops, and to optimize code by not only vectorizing code  2) but also taking advantage of GPU in Matlab. 3) And to see whether GPU can win in all tasks from CPU or in some cases.

Comment: @khan Your attempt to 'minimize' has now made the question worse: variable names have lost their meaning. Of course you can't make your code 'shorter' if you are asking us to do your translation. But that's not how SE works: **you** do the translation work and where you are stuck on details, you ask here. So start writing your GPU code, use online documentation, and come back here for specific parts that don't work. And leave out the optimization part, that is for later.

Comment: I agree. Thanks to all of you for your guidance. I am new and i am trying. and so nice of you all.  Regards

Answer (score 3):

Few points to be noted here -

1. GPUs in general don't like conditional statements as they cause divergence.
   So, we must aim to get rid of those here.
2. It would be a tiring job to look at all of the code in the question in one go. So, we must take small steps towards optimization. The first step would be vectorizing the innermost nested loops, so that things could be done in parallel, a philosophy preferred by GPUs for performance.

This is the code we tackled to start with -

```
for Up_map_sens = map_to_read % this states which three maps ...
    UpperLayer_Sensitivity = cur_sensitivites(:,:,Up_map_sens);
    if(inhibatory==0) % this if it is in receptive field
        summed_value = summed_value + ...
                 sum(sum(UpperLayer_Sensitivity(uLowMax:uHighMax,vLowMax:vHighMax)));
    else % it is in inhibitory field but as we have 0 so not used currently
        for u = uLowMax : uHighMax
            for v = vLowMax : vHighMax
                if(u>=uLow && u<= uHigh && v>=vLow &&v<=vHigh)
                    summed_value = summed_value + UpperLayer_Sensitivity(u,v);
                else
                    summed_value = summed_value - UpperLayer_Sensitivity(u,v);
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The vectorized version of the above code could be something like this -

```
%// Get size
[m,n,p] = size(cur_sensitivites);

%// You basically have two subarrays, one is bigger and another smaller but
%// a subset of the bigger one. Get the sum of these two.

%// Get the linear indices for the bigger array and finally sum of all it
ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,[uLowMax:uHighMax]',([vLowMax:vHighMax]-1)*m); %//'
ind2 = bsxfun(@plus,ind1(:),(map_to_read-1)*m*n);
mv = sum(cur_sensitivites(ind2(:)));

%// Get the linear indices for the smaller subset array and finally sum it all
ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,[uLow:uHigh]',([vLow:vHigh]-1)*m); %//'
ind2 = bsxfun(@plus,ind1(:),(map_to_read-1)*m*n);
pv = sum(cur_sensitivites(ind2(:)));

%// Get conditional value and the final output - summed_value
cond1 = inhibatory==0;
summed_value = mv.*cond1 + (-mv+2*pv).*(~cond1);
```

Thus, to use GPU for calculations, you need to copy your data to GPU with calls to `gpuArray(...)` at the start. You may leave the scalars as they are. Take this as a start, as three innermost nested loops alongwith the dreaded conditional statement are down and you are only left with a couple more nested loops.

Comment: This assumes - `uLowMax` is lesser than or equal to `uLow` and `uHighMax` is grater than or equal to `uHigh`. Similarly for the column indices.

Comment: I will reply after a while with detail, But currently one comment is that ||%// With "for Up_map_sens = map_to_read" || in this case i have loop in most cases, only in first and last case i dont have loop. But maximum of 1<=map_to_read<=3 loops in each case.

Comment: @khan So in that case keep the loop - `for Up_map_sens = map_to_read,   UpperLayer_Sensitivity = cur_sensitivites(:,:,Up_map_sens);..[Vectorized code from the solution above] ..end
`

Comment: @khan Also, is `map_to_read` a row vector? Give me its size?

Comment: no i have a matrix of 0's and 1's. suppose here we consider it as 13x11. Each column consist of 3 consecutive 1's. e.g cc=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0; 1,0,0,0,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,1,0,0,0,0,0; 0,1,0,0,0,0,0; 0,1,0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,1,0,0,0,0; 0,0,1,0,0,0,0; 0,0,1,0,0,0,0]; and when i apply find(cc(cur_layer,:)); it gives me the 1's indices in that row

Comment: OK. I will, I am trying to access my lab computer but net is slow, as it works i will test it, as i dont have gpu on my laptop right now...

Comment: @khan So, it appears that if `cc` is a 2D matrix, `find(cc(cur_layer,:))` would be a row vector, right?

Comment: yes exactly, 1x1, 1x2, 1x3

Comment: @khan Ok, so try the suggestion as posted earlier - `for Up_map_sens = map_to_read,   UpperLayer_Sensitivity = cur_sensitivites(:,:,Up_map_sens);..[Vectorized code from the solution above] ..end`, with one edit - `summed_value = summed_value +  mv.*cond1 + (-mv+2*pv).*(~cond1);`

Comment: That worked, currently upto the innermost loops.  but one question is it good to convert all data at once to gpuArray. Or no its ok to convert and than gather from gpu each time.

Comment: @khan Check out the edits. Hope this helps! `gather` only at the end.

Comment: Yeah i noted that before, and even i converted it to gpuArray. and than gathered the data out of it. and the result is same for both interm of output,

Comment: @khan Check out the edits as one more nested loop is removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61521/discussion-between-khan-and-divakar).

Comment: Will be back on Monday. Cant access my computer. So further discussion will be on monday... To improve the speed. As till now we changed but GPU is worse than CPU in this case.

Comment: @khan The thing with GPU codes, its preferred to have all the data used in the codes to be copied over to GPU, because the performance   isn't maximized when you have mixed (CPU and GPU data) working together as that case calls for a lot of CPU-GPU memory transfers.

Comment: OK i will try to convert all variables in that function to GPU and will see today...

Comment: I have converted everything to gpuArray format. But now you can say its taking more time than before (with un-vectorized code). Did you mean the same of converting everything to GPU format?

Comment: @khan Yes everything (except scalars) to its GPU version. So `tempGrad = gpuArray(tempGrad)` and so on.

Comment: i did everything, Only the variables such as indices e.g (rowStart:rowEnd,colStart,colEnd) . Because it gives error, the rest all to gpuArray().

Comment: @khan Were you able to remove all nested loops?

Comment: no, not yet, i am trying, and also trying to understand the indexing step that you have done. Because i didn't understood that. However, i am trying to minimize and simplisize my problem. Than will upload in a question.

Comment: @khan So unless you remove all nested loops, I don't think you would see the full potential of GPUs and thus, its performance would continue to be inferior when compared against its CPU couterpart.

Comment: I agree, i have to give time to this. I think i have to prioritize my code in this regards. However in the previous question i found an error. did you checked that post of mine?